Rename field name in nested array of subdocuments for all documents
I have a collection like this:
[
  {
    "variants": [
      {
        "fruits": [
          {
            "bad_name": "Banana"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Now I want to rename the field bad_name to good_name.
[
  {
    "variants": [
      {
        "fruits": [
          {
            "good_name": "Banana"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

I tried first using $rename but that did not work:
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$rename": {
      "variants.$.fruits.$.bad_name": "good_name"
    }
  }
])

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-I8ewTLuisT
Then I tried an overly complicated looking way I found which also did not work:
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "variants.fruits": {
        $map: {
          input: "$variants.fruits",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                fruits: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.fruits",
                    in: {
                      good_name: "$$this.bad_name"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]) 

https://mongoplayground.net/p/f8EXddVOvVa
Is there any easy way to simply rename a field in a subdocument located in a deeply nested array?
Thanks for your help!

You should iterate the element in the variants array and in each variant element, you also required to iterate the element in the fruits array.
Lastly, remove the bad_name field with $unset stage.
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      variants: {
        $map: {
          input: "$variants",
          as: "v",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$v",
              {
                fruits: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$v.fruits",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          good_name: "$$this.bad_name"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "variants.fruits.bad_name"
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground
